Redirect to wp login if user is not logged in
I am trying to redirect a non-logged-in site visitor to the WordPress log-in page if they click on a Menu link if they are not logged in and display the form if they are logged in. The menu link (that points to delete.php page) is inside a custom bootstrap static page.
Any help?
here is the code contained in the delete.php page that the Nav link points to:
<?php
      if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       echo <<<RGN
        <form id="plugin_delete_me_shortcode_form" method="post">
            <p>
            WARNING!<br /><br />Are you sure you want to delete user %username% from %sitename%?
            <p/>
        <p>
        <label for="plugin_delete_me_shortcode_password">
            Password
        </label>
        <input type="password" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" id="plugin_delete_me_shortcode_password" name="plugin_delete_me_shortcode_password" />
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Confirm Deletion" /></p>
        </form>
RGN;
        exit;
    } else {
        wp_redirect('https://example.com/wp-login.php');
        exit;
   
?>

The redirect to the log-in page though is not working.

If your theme is setup correctly, there will be a class .logged-in added to the <body> if the user is logged in. If that is not the case, you will need to add it using custom code.
So let's take advantage of that and write some JavaScript code.


function isLogged() {
  return document.body.classList.contains("logged-in")
}


document.querySelector(".link-delete").addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (isLogged()) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    console.log("show modal with content of delete.php maybe even iframe")
  } else {
    ev.target.href = "https://example.com/wp-login.php"
  }
})
<body class="logged-in">

  <nav>
    <a href="delete.php" class="link-delete">delete</a>
  </nav>
</body>



